# X-pages Custom control palette is missing even if the custom controls are present

Tags: xpages, custom-controls, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a project cloned on my local machine for example the name is Example-Template, I have created a Template (example.ntf) from designer and associated this (example.ntf) with the on-disk project (Example-Template), All the x-pages and custom controls are visible in the (example.ntf) in project side tabs inside the x-pages tab and custom-control tabs respectively. Till here everthing this is perfect.

The problem occurs now is

1.The custom control tab in palette at the right side of the designer is not visible So it is impossible to use the custom-control in any x-page.

2.All the custom controls which are visible in custom control in project side shows an error wherever I have used ant custom control.
For example the errors are on the code.

```
    <xc:cc_controlOptions></xc:cc_controlOptions>
```

So the custom-control "cc_controlOptions" is present in the custom controls list even after that the error says "The Unknown tag xc:cc_controlOptions cannot be used as a control.

Usually this comes when we dont add the tag specification in view tag of the page but have the "xc" tag specified in  tag the code is

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" 
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
```

3. The last and important thing is that the custom control tab is missing from the palette at the right side of designer as shown in image.

Hope the image will clear my issues.

[image: Designer screen shot]

Comment: What kind of errors do you have if you expand them in the Problems tab? It seems that the on-disk-project (ODP) does not contain the config-parts of the custom controls so that they are not recognized at all by DDE which results in the missing Custom Control area. You have to fix those errors first or (and that would be the more reasonable scenario) get a fixed and complete ODP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems 'Oliver Busse' is nearly close to the solution of my issue.

I have created a new custom-control in the same project, I successfully able to create the custom controls with no errors, but after that, when I have explored the custom control folder, I seen that all the 'meta-data' were missing of the rest custom controls except the new custom control.

So as 'Oliver Busse' commented, the config-parts of the custom controls are present but the meta data was missing.

The ignorance of all meta data files were because of git ignore file.In the git ignore file don't know how there was .metadata files added and because of that when I have pushed it on git server it has ignored all the metadata.

So basically whole issue is because I have cloned a project to another machine without metadata files of custom controls.Both config files and metadata files could cause this issue.